# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in juncBASE

Tags: command-line, python-2.7

I am new to python and I want to do Alternative splicing Discovery by juncBase but at the first step of the juncBase's Manual I have a error:

```
sabah@sabah-virtual-machine:~/juncBase/juncBASE_v0.6 $ python2.7 runCufflinks.py -i IlluminaHBM_2.0_samp2test_bam.txt --txt_ref UCSC.hg19.knownGene_w_gene_symbol_EnsemblChr.gtf --out_dir /home/sabah/juncBase/juncBASE_v0.6/out --num_processes 2
cufflinks -o /home/sabah/juncBase/juncBASE_v0.6/out/kidney_cufflinks -g UCSC.hg19.knownGene_w_gene_symbol_EnsemblChr.gtf -u kidney.bam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runCufflinks.py", line 242, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "runCufflinks.py", line 201, in main
    Popen(cmd, shell=True, executable=SHELL)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can you help me? When I typed `python2.7 runCufflinks.py`, the arguments of this command are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Python can't find a file mentioned. Looking at the [source code and manual](http://compbio.berkeley.edu/proj/juncbase/juncBASE_v0.6.tgz), it mentions this:

> You may need to modify this file [IlluminaHBM_2.0_samp2test_bam.txt]
>   to specify the full path of the bam files

So in your case you may not have downloaded the test files or need to edit **IlluminaHBM_2.0_samp2test_bam.txt** to look something like this:

```
kidney  /home/sabah/juncBase/juncBASE_v0.6/kidney.bam
breast  /home/sabah/juncBase/juncBASE_v0.6/breast.bam
adrenal /home/sabah/juncBase/juncBASE_v0.6/adrenal.bam
colon   /home/sabah/juncBase/juncBASE_v0.6/colon.bam
lung    /home/sabah/juncBase/juncBASE_v0.6/lung.bam
liver   /home/sabah/juncBase/juncBASE_v0.6/liver.bam
```

Comment: updating : my problem was the num_processes Argument that should be 1 .